# Plivo Invalid XML

Tags: xml, plivo

I am making a call from mobile phone to a plivo number. In the answer URL I have given an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<Response> 
    <Speak>Hey How are you.</Speak>
</Response>
```

But, when I make a call. I get the following error

> "Message : XML : Invalid XML Syntax: not well-formed (invalid token):
>   line 1, column 1795"

Is there anything that has to be corrected.
Reference: http://docs.plivo.org/docs/restxml/elements/speak/.  (Archived copy [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170425111912/docs.plivo.org/docs/restxml/elements/speak/); complete documentation now available as located by [TChilds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9237191/tchilds) here: https://brandedbridgeline.com/plivo_docs/.)

Comment: Try manually deleting the quotes and retyping them. Sometimes if you copy and paste the quotes get whacked out and mess things up. Just a shot in the dark but, give it a try.

Comment: Do you have anything above or below this code in your file?

Comment: Still no luck... I dont have code other than the one mentioned.

Comment: @zephyr `column 1795` suggests you have :)

Comment: @iehrlich I didn't get you and the first line has characters < 100, so column 1795 doesn't make sense to me. Moreover, if I validate XML using http://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0
It appears to be a valid one

Comment: @zephyr not need to pass xml version info <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

Comment: @zephyr FYI here is my sample response and its working proper way. <Response><Record callbackUrl="recording_url" callbackMethod="POST" startOnDialAnswer="true" redirect="true" maxLength="3600"/><Dial action="action_url" method="POST" redirect="true" ><Number>xxxxxxxxxxx</Number></Dial></Response>.